# Numpy / PyTorch - how to assign value with indices in different dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor

Suppose I have a matrix and some indices

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
a_indices = np.array([[0,2], [1,2]])
```

Is there any efficient way to achieve following operation?

```
for i in range(2):
    a[i, a_indices[i]] = 100

# a: np.array([[100, 2, 100], [4, 100, 100]])
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html) -

```
In [111]: np.put_along_axis(a,a_indices,100,axis=1)

In [112]: a
Out[112]: 
array([[100,   2, 100],
       [  4, 100, 100]])
```

Alternaytively, if you want to do with the explicit way, i.e. integer-based indexing -

```
In [115]: a[np.arange(len(a_indices))[:,None], a_indices] = 100
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this question is [tagged with PyTorch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pytorch), here is a PyTorch equivalent solution just for the sake of completeness.

```
# make a copy of the inputs from numpy array
In [188]: at = torch.tensor(a)
In [189]: at_idxs = torch.tensor(a_indices)
```

We will make use of [`tensor.scatter_(...)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) to do the replacement **in-place**. So, let's prepare the inputs first.

[`torch.scatter()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) API expects the replacement value (here `100`) to be a tensor **and** of the same shape as the indices tensor. Thus, we have to create a tensor filled with a value of `100` and of the shape `(2, 2)` since the indices tensor `at_idxs` is of that shape. So,

```
In [190]: replace_val = 100 * torch.ones(at_idxs.shape, dtype=torch.long)    
In [191]: replace_val 
Out[191]: 
tensor([[100, 100],
        [100, 100]])
```

Perform the **in-place replacement** now:

```
# fill the values along dimension 1
In [198]: at.scatter_(1, at_idxs, replace_val)
Out[198]: 
tensor([[100,   2, 100],
        [  4, 100, 100]])
```